# Why steepest descent gives a wrong direction search?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, computational-mathematics

I have to minimize the function $ƒ(x_1,x_2)=(x_1-1)^2+x_2^3-x_1x_2$. The initial point is $[1,1]^T$.

The gradient of this function is $∇ƒ(x_1,x_2)=[2(x_1-1)-x_2,3x_2^2-x1]$. This gradient evaluated in the initial point is $∇ƒ(1,1)=[-1,2]$. Following the steepest descent method it is mandatory to minimize the function $ƒ(x_0-α∇ƒ(x_0))$ in order to find the value of $α$. So $ƒ(x_0-α∇ƒ(x_0))=-5α+15α^2-8α^3$ and $ƒ'(x_0-α∇ƒ(x_0))=-5+30α-24α^2$. This function has extreme points in $α_1=0.95061$ and $α_2=5.094$. In order to be a minimum of this curve $ƒ''(x_0-α∇ƒ(x_0))=30-48α$ has to be positive. This is my problem $ƒ''(x_0-α∇ƒ(x_0))$ evaluated at both $α$ values is negative so they don't minimize the direction. So what I am doing wrong?

Comment: $-5+30\alpha-24\alpha^2=0$ seems to lead to [another result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%E2%88%925%CE%B1%2B15%CE%B1%5E2%E2%88%928%CE%B1%5E3%29%27%3D0)

Comment: You're totally right! I made a mistake when I solved this equation. You saved me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have other question related to this problem. Following forward with this method I get both $α$ values negative in the second iteration and one of them minimizes the curve, however by definition the $α$ value that minimizes the curve has to be positive. Hope I didn't make a mistake in my calculations. What happens when I got in a situation like this?